# Eror setting Header for TabItem: Specified element is already the logical child of another element

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to set the header for a TabItem that is bound to an ObservableCollection. When adding the second item to the list I get the error `Specified element is already the logical child of another element.` From reading some of the answers in SO I understand that the construct I've chosen will add the TextBlock twice. But I have no clue how I would do it correctly.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <!--This works: <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}" />-->
            <Setter Property="Header">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
</Window>
```

Here the C# part:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Tabs { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Tabs = new<string>();
        Tabs.Add("Hello");
        Tabs.Add("World"); // Error: "Specified element is already the logical child of another element."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Visual` can be used only in one place in the visual tree. By adding another `TabItem` you try to use it more then one place. You can use `HeaderTemplate` instead of setting `Header` directly which will create `Header` content from the `DataTemplate` for each `TabItem`

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are technically creating two `TextBlock` when you call `Tabs.Add`, because you are not using `DataTemplates`. It is technically reusing the `Header` value which is connected to the first item tab and then the second tab will try to reuse that one.

It will be better to use `DataTemplates` so that it will just create a new `UIElement` value to attach to the parent.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```